# Limit tag depth on given html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked on SO for a while and can't find and answer.

Say I have a set of nested tags in an html string:

```
<blockquote>
    <blockquote>
        <blockquote>
            <blockquote>
                Some Text 1
            </blockquote>
            Some Text 2
        </blockquote>
    Some Text 3
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
    Text!
        <blockquote>
        Text 2!
        </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
Some Text 4
</blockquote>
```

In jquery, how do I take that html string and convert it to another html string but removing the nth nested blockquote. So if I limited it to two, this would remain:

```
<blockquote>
    <blockquote>
    Some Text 3
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
    Text!
    </blockquote>
Some Text 4
</blockquote>
```

Preferably, the function's prototype should look like this:

```
var limit = 2;
myHtmlString = limitQuotes(myHtmlString, limit);
```

Any direction on the matter would be helpful.

Comment: Don't try to do anything with the string. Turn it into actual DOM Nodes. Then a simple recursive traversal algorithm will do. Maybe with  jQuery there is an even faster way .. something like `$("blockquote>blockquote>blockquote").remove()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Doge's comment:

```
function limitQuotes(html, max_depth){
    var depth_selector = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < max_depth; i++){
        depth_selector += '>blockquote';
    }
    html = $(html);
    html.find(depth_selector).remove();
    return html.wrap('<p>').parent().html();
}

$('body').html(limitQuotes('<blockquote><blockquote><blockquote><blockquote>Some Text 1</blockquote>Some Text 2</blockquote>Some Text 3</blockquote><blockquote>Text!<blockquote>Text 2!</blockquote></blockquote>Some Text 4</blockquote>',2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AA67d/6/

note: better suited variable names would be a help.

Comment: Almost! When original html has a depth of 1 however it strips the blockquote out (e.g. <blockquote>my text</blockquote> )

Comment: Actually, why is this removing the first <blockquote> ?

Comment: Good question, it's odd :/

Comment: All I can suggest is returning `return '<blockquote>' + html.html() + '</blockquote>';` which is a slightly hacky. Let me keep having a look.

Comment: Can't do that, in practice the <blockquote> has attributes that need to be kept